# Farseer span between objects

Tags: box2d, physics-engine, farseer

There is situation: object "A" falls down on static object "B", but when "A" lands on "B" there is span between "A" and "B". How to solve the issues?

Comment: are you sure that what you are seeing on the screen, and what the physics engine is doing, are the same? Box2D has the debug draw feature to help with that.

Comment: I debug and see that values are not correct, for example, y coord is "3.598" but should be 3.6 !

Answer (score 1):

Box2d is using iterative solver and the quality of simulation depends on numerical values you use in simulation. In box2d manual is recommended to keep dynamic body's dimensions in range [0.1, 10] for example. The accuracy 0.002 (from your comment) is a very good one.

So there are two ways to solve your problem. Change the measuring system you use or increase position and/or velocity iterations. First way is much better because it will not increase the calculation time.

Comment: I found solution to shrink physics object from his presentation, for example, i have textured block 60x60 px so i create physics rectangle of 58x58 and it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Box2d has `b2_linearSlop` parameter (AKA 'Skin' in PhysX)

It's a little addition to the size of geometry to improve stability of physics simulations. Maybe it causes the artefacts described by you.

Try to look for the following strings in the source code of box2d (I've taken it from flash port of the original box2d, nonetheless it should be the same for other platforms):

```
/**
* A small length used as a collision and constraint tolerance. Usually it is
* chosen to be numerically significant, but visually insignificant.
*/
static public const b2_linearSlop:Number = 0.005;   // 0.5 cm
```